# Encoding problems when extracting text with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction, pypdf

I am using PyPDF2 to extract text from a pdf file. It works but it doesn't understand accented characters.

Here's my code :

```
filename ='document.pdf' 

#open allows you to read the file
pdfFileObj = open(filename,'rb')

#The pdfReader variable is a readable object that will be parsed
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

#discerning the number of pages will allow us to parse through all the pages
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages


count = 0
text = ""

#The while loop will read each page
while count < num_pages:                      
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()
    
if text != "":
    text = text
```

This is the result I have :

```
82 %G’nes dues au bruitEurop”ens expos”s ‹ des seuils 
au del‹ de 55 dB.125 MDes habitants dÕIle de France expos”s ‹ des 
valeurs sup”rieures recommand”s par lÕOMS.
90 %Des fran“ais se disent pr”occup”s par 
les questions relatives au bruit.
82 %Personnes d”clarent ’tre g’n”s par des 
nuisances sonores ‹ leur domicile.
45 %Les effets du bruit caus”s chaque ann”es
Les effets du bruit caus”s chaque ann”es
Personnes g’n”es par le bruit.
```

And this is what the pdf looks like :

[image]

Comment: Is this Python3 or Python2?

Comment: It's in Python3

Comment: @Soph can you post some of your text within the question?

Comment: This might be an off-the-wall idea but are you sure the text contents of the PDF actually match the image on screen? Text is an PDF is stored in a different layer than the image version, so it's often not visible if the underlying text layer is wrong. If the text was badly encoded when the PDF was created, you won't get anything useful from that, you'd have to OCR the image layer instead (tesseract for example).

Comment: `https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/` this module might be useful

Comment: @Alan I think you're right and I might use tesseract.

Comment: @Ajay thank you, I will check it out !

Comment: @Soph An easy way to test would be to open the file in a PDF reader and manually copy and paste into a text editor

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's your code. I think it's an issue with the PDF.

I checked using a sample PDF file: https://www.languagebird.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/sample_French_Basics_Grammar_Book-2017-3.pdf

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Note you don't need to manually open a file object
# You can pass a string reference to a file
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('sample_French_Basics_Grammar_Book-2017-3.pdf')

text = ""

# Better to loop through the pages using the iterator
# Rather than manual count
for current_page in pdfReader.pages:
    text += current_page.extractText()

# Output the results
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

You'll note from the contents of 'output.txt' that the accented characters are represented correctly. The only text error is smart quotes in the wrong code points which would have to be handled.

The output of `extractText()` is a unicode string and therefore should not have any issues with accented characters provided the source is correctly encoded.

The structure of PDF is to separate the image layer and the text layer. The image layer is often the top layer in order to give it a neater appearance. Unfortunately it means you can't see with the naked eye any issues with the underlying text. Without seeing the PDF you are working on, I suspect the text added to the PDF when it was created was incorrect.